# Azure Webjobs vs RunBooks vs Schedulars :How to choose?

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-scheduler, runbook

Am beginner to using Azure Services, In what scenarios we have to go with **WebJobs & RunBooks & Schedulars**. what is the difference between them.

Comment: Have you read the documentation ? :-)

Answer (score 5):

[Azure Scheduler](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/scheduler-intro/) permits to call http endpoints and send messages in Azure Storage Queues or Azure Service bus periodically.

[Azure Webjobs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/) permits to execute programs or scripts in an Azure Web App "context" : it's stored in an Azure Web App folder. We can consider webjobs as background tasks.
All of the following programs or scripts are accepted (.jar, .js, .py, .php, .sh, .ps1, .cmd, .bat). Web jobs can be executed continually, periodically (using CRON expression) or on demand.

[Azure Automation Runbooks](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/automation-intro/) permits to execute PowerShell scripts periodically. Runbooks can access all Azure Services and external services.

Azure Webjobs and Azure Automation runbooks use Azure scheduler in the background.